# For $p\ge3$ there is no extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ with Galois group $S_4$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

I'm trying to show that if $p\ge3$ is prime, then

> There is no extension $K$ of the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_p$ with Galois group $S_4$.

I know that $K$ must have a subextension $K'$ that is unramified over $\mathbb Q_p$, and that $\operatorname{Gal}(K' /\mathbb Q_p)$ must be cyclic. From this I can deduce that the inertia subgroup $I$ is either $S_4$ or $A_4$, since it must be a normal subgroup of $S_4$ with cyclic quotient.

At this point I'm stuck. I've tried playing around with higher ramification groups, using the fact that $G_1$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $I$, and I think I can use this to show the $p=3$ case, but haven't been able to get further than this.

I would very much appreciate a hint!

Comment: Aren't the higher ramification groups always $p$-groups? And the only normal Sylow subgroup of $A_4$ is with $p=2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen they are, but if $p\gt3$, I haven't been able to rule out all of them being trivial. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious

Comment: $G/G_0$ is cyclic, and $G_0/G_1$ is cyclic of order coprime with $p$. So if $G_1$ is trivial, then $G_0$ has to be cyclic

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and there's the obvious fact I'm missing! I seem to have forgotten that finite fields have cyclic multiplicative groups. Thanks

Comment: Well done. I was a bit lost at selected points trying to recall the numbering :-)